# How to extract integer from a string in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have this variable **Code** in erlang which has this value `"T00059"`

I want to extract this value `59` from **Code**.

I try to extract with this code this value  `"00059"`.

```erlang
NewCode = string:substr(Code, 2, length(Code)),
```

Now I want to know  how can we eliminate the first zero before the first integer not null. I mean how can we extract  `"59"`?

For example if I have this value `"Z00887"` I should have in the final this value  `887`.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply do (output from an interactive `erl`session):

```
1> Code = "Z00887",
1> {NewCode, _Rest} = string:to_integer(string:substr(Code, 2, length(Code))),
1> NewCode.
887
```

(My answer in [test with loop in erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813593/test-with-loop-in-erlang) goes into more detail regarding the same problem)

Answer (score 1):

This code will skip starting zeros. If you want to save them change `$1` to `$0`

```
extract_integer([]) -> [];
extract_integer([H|T]) when (H >= $1) and (H =< $9) -> [H] ++ T;
extract_integer([_H|T]) -> extract_integer(T).
```

Comment: can you explain a bit?